# Intellij Idea: how to retrieve class files from a project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I nave managed to get a reference to the currently selected project in the actionPerformed method of a custom action in a plugin i am developing.
How can I iterate through the class files contained in the out directory ?